# [Penalties]: How to force new page when not enough room on page?

Tags: formatting, page-breaking

This is *not* a duplicate of *preventing* a pagebreak.

## What I want to achieve

Consider an `itemize` environment, where one of the `\item`s are split over the bottom of one page and the beginning of the next:

I want the `\item` (alternatively the entire `itemize` environment) to go on top of the next page instead of being split over two pages.

However, if there is any (reasonable) way to put it on the current page, then it should prioritize that.

I want this to be done *automatically*, so without e.g. `needspace` package.

## What I've tried

I suspect this will be done with penalties. I've been playing around with the ones in the `\samepage` definition as well as the ones listed [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51263/what-are-penalties-and-which-ones-are-defined).

For example `\@itempenalty\@M` does not work, which makes me a little puzzled.

It might just be that I don't quite understand what the penalties actually do. I understand it so that if a certain penalty is high then the interpreter will attempt to avoid breaking at this penalty. What I don't understand is how to encourage the page break iff there is no way that it can insert the content (under normal restrictions).

## Code

I'm working on a package, and this is just a MWE.

The itemize splits across pages, and in this example there is no room, so I want the `itemize` environment (I'm also fine with just the `\item` in question) to jump to the next page. (I added a `\makeatletter` so you don't have to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \bgroup 
    %\bgroup is okay here, right? 
    % (Then the penalties should go back at \egroup?)

    %% Magic, amazing penalty code can go here. %%
    %% ... or wherever it fits best ...         %%

    \begin{itemize}
      \item\lipsum[10-12]
    \end{itemize}
  \egroup
\end{document}
```

---

This is not really a question about penalties, although I wouldn't mind links or explanations that would clarify how the compiler (i.e. pdftex) deals with penalties.

Thanks in advance, guys :)

---

Feel free to suggest, or do, edits to the title so it's more to the core of the problem. I feel a little on thin ice with this title?

Comment: You could put the `itemize` environment in a `minipage`, to prevent it breaking up.

Comment: That like a hacky fix? I'll give it a go though.

Comment: I wouldn't call it hacky.  It's the ultimate penalty...it won't pagebreak in the middle.

Comment: By the way, if you try the `minipage`in your MWE, you need to use the `[b]` option, to get the exit spacing right.  You may need to add a `\strut` to you first `\item`.  Else, use the `[t]` option and add a `\strut` at the end of the last `\item`.

Comment: Look for `\filbreak`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `\filbreak` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72787/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{itemize}\preto\item{\filbreak}
\item test\\on\\three lines
\item test
\item\lipsum[10-12]
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\preto` does what it seems to do? "Before every..."?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman The `\preto` command prepends tokens to a parameterless macro, in this case `\item` (only locally, so at the end of `itemize` the change will be undone. So when LaTeX processes `\item` it will first do `\filbreak`, then the normal action of `\item`.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `\filbreak` *after* the `itemize` environment too? Otherwise, TeX might prefer a page break before the last item, even if it would fit on the page. (Or so I think.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen That’s quite likely